# How can I get this "search bar" working with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have a one page app that is separated by tabs, its pretty much a list of links coming from a database. I want to create a type of search or filter, I don't want to hit the database for it. From my understanding, something like angular could do this but I don't know how so I was hoping someone can show me in jquery. Here is what I tried so far:

```
 <html>
   <form method="POST" action="#">{% csrf_token %}


  <div class="row collapse"> 
    <div class="small-9 columns">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search Song Titles" />
    </div>
    <div class="small-3 columns">
      <button id="hide" type="submit" class="postfix">Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  </form>

 {% for v in videos %}
    <div data-which="video_search" data-videotitle="{{search_value}}"(i get this by sending it through the form)>
        {{v}}

    </div>
 {% endfor %}

 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
        $('[data-which="video_search"]').hide();
        $('[data-videotitle="{{search_value}}"]').show();
                          });});      

        (Javscript for the Tabs -  sort of irrelevant I think, I put it in case its not)
        $(document).foundation({   
        tab: {
        callback : function (tab) {
        console.log(tab);
        }
      }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: you want the search functionality to be done using jQuery...??

Comment: Preferably yes, I'd stay away from doing server side if I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery something like this might help u mate.. :)

```
 $("button").click(function(){
      var searchBox = $("#searchBox").val();  //Gets the value of the searchbox where `searchBox` is the id of the input field
      $('[data-which="video_search"]').hide();
      $('[data-videotitle^="'+searchBox+'"]').show(); 
 });
```

Check this fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f9o6f01v/)

Comment: Sorry youre right I implemented it wrong, its almost perfect, just one thing, when you type in a search word, it seems to be case sensitive, is there any way around that?

Answer (score 0):

So what you mean is that you want to create a search with Angular Js!! right

1.Download angularjs from angularjs.org
2.link it to your html file
3.then check out this, Angular filter doc : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Example coding for a simple search

```
<div ng-init="friends = [{name:'John', phone:'555-1276'},
                                   {name:'Mary', phone:'800-BIG-MARY'},
                                   {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321'},
                                   {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678'},
                                   {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765'},
                                   {name:'Juliette', phone:'555-5678'}]"></div>

          Search:
          <input ng-model="searchText">
          <table id="searchTextResults">
              <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Phone</th>
              </tr>
              <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText">
                  <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
                  <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
              </tr>
          </table>
          <hr> Any:
          <input ng-model="search.$">
          <br> Name only
          <input ng-model="search.name">
          <br> Phone only
          <input ng-model="search.phone">
          <br> Equality
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="strict">
          <br>
          <table id="searchObjResults">
              <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Phone</th>
              </tr>
              <tr ng-repeat="friendObj in friends | filter:search:strict">
                  <td>{{friendObj.name}}</td>
                  <td>{{friendObj.phone}}</td>
              </tr>
          </table>
```

Comment: Problem for me is that im using django and my "friends" list is coming from the db

Comment: Then get the data from db as json format and then pass it to angular
you can reffer django json here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/serialization/